# Why does "apt-get install" not check GPG Key before installation?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I create a key by 
    `gpg --get-key` &
    `gpg -a --export --output mykey.gpg.key`
then resign a deb package with
    `dpkg-sig --sign builder XYZ.deb`.
I assume when I run `apt-get install XYZ.deb`, I will be asked for a password, but it is not.
It was installed directlly.
How come?
Where do I get wrong?
Please clue me.
Thanks,

Comment: Password? For what?

Comment: When you run `gpg -a --export --output mykey.gpg.key`, you will need to set a passphrase.

Comment: ok, but that's for your private key. Why would your public key, which is what apt will use to verify the signature, be protected by a password?

Comment: Ya, you got the point. I assume when I run `apt-get install XYZ.deb`, the system will verify the key. But because I didn't publish my public key yet and it didn't check or ask during the process, just install the deb package directly. I though it supposes to ask me password or where the key is or something else for double check. It is not a secure process to install the package without a public key.

Comment: usually installing a package directly from a Deb file will be exempted from signature verification because the assumption is that the user knows what they'll be doing. Set up a local repository and try installing from it and apt will start complaining quickly

Comment: @muru Thank you. You have the same point as the link , https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/